# changing the format of a usb drive

Tags: filesystems, tree

I have a usb drive that once I type in the tree command. I have one file that is out of place. It is located at the bottom of the tree and need to move it.

```
F:.
├───DATA
├───GAMES
│   ├───MATCH32
│   ├───BOG2
│   └───MLINK
├───LEVEL-1
│   └───LEVEL-2
│       └───LEVEL-3
├───MEDIA
│   ├───TV
│   ├───MOVIES
│   └───BOOKS
├───MUSIC
├───SPORTS
└───TEST
```

I need to move the data file below the media file, above music.

Comment: Thank you for the revised format of the question. Any suggestions/answers?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why do you want `data` between `Media` and `Music` - that makes no sense - Data, media, music - are all on the root directory and it doesn't matter where on the tree the data folder is located.

Comment: I believe the tree command is sorted automatically.

Comment: In my homework assignment I need to use the tree that is the same as the teachers. For some reason mine id off by that one file. So if I was to use a dir command using a relative path and started in media and went to data it would not be able to find it. (i.E. dir media/data should show me the data file on the appropriate tree. on my tree it would not work.

Comment: It would also help if you referenced things correctly, is `DATA` a folder or a file since `MEDIA` clearly is a directory. I would also consider the fact that your teacher made a mistake or you're actually suppose to notice the error.

Comment: @Dan If your current directory is `MEDIA` and you wanted to use `DIR` to see the files in `DATA` the command would be `DIR ..\DATA`.  The `..` means to go to the parent directory.  Using `DIR MEDIA\DATA` would work if you were in the root directory and `DATA` was a subdirectory of `MEDIA`. (barring any symbolic or hard linking tricks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open up Windows Explorer and move the file from the current directory to the correct directory.

Answer (score 3):

The tree is sorted alphabetically. If you really want to order the folders custom (and this method will require name change of all the folders) then prefix numbers to all the folder names. So change you structure to:

```
F:.

├───1GAMES
│   ├───MATCH32
│   ├───BOG2
│   └───MLINK
├───2LEVEL-1
│   └───LEVEL-2
│       └───LEVEL-3
├───3MEDIA
│   ├───TV
│   ├───MOVIES
│   └───BOOKS
|   
|───4DATA
├───5MUSIC
├───6SPORTS
└───7TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is you want your folders:

```
F:.

├───GAMES
│   ├───MATCH32
│   ├───BOG2
│   └───MLINK
├───LEVEL-1
│   └───LEVEL-2
│       └───LEVEL-3
├───MEDIA
│   ├───TV
│   ├───MOVIES
│   |───BOOKS
|   └───DATA
├───MUSIC
├───SPORTS
└───TEST
```

in this case, from the command prompt, type:

```
cd \
f:
mkdir media/data
xcopy data/* media/data  /e
del /s /f data/*
rmdir data
```

Comment: Data need to stand alone not part of the media file. It is a seperate file(i.E. data, music sports etc. not part of media

Comment: If data is not under media, moving it makes no sense. Relative paths will work regardless of where they "shown" on tree.

Comment: the way you have data isn't under media it's in media it is supposed to be a seperate file. Not a subdirectory of a file. LIKE MUSIC SPORTS TEST