# moving to sub-directories

Tags: linux, windows

How do I move to level-3 (the subdirectory of level-1) in my following directory from the root?

```
F:.
├───DATA
├───GAMES
│   ├───MATCH32
│   ├───BOG2
│   └───MLINK
├───LEVEL-1
│   └───LEVEL-2
│       └───LEVEL-3
├───MEDIA
│   ├───TV
│   ├───MOVIES
│   └───BOOKS
├───MUSIC
├───SPORTS
└───TEST
```

Comment: can you be more clear what you are trying to accomplish.  What are you moving?  What OS?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/203761/changing-the-format-of-a-usb-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move to the directory or move a **file** to the directory?

to move to the directory itself:

```
cd LEVEL-1/LEVEL-2/LEVEL-3
```

to move a file:

```
move file LEVEL-1/LEVEL-2/LEVEL-3
```

swap `move` for `mv` on a UNIX-based OS.

Comment: If you add an initial slash, then it will work no matter where you start from: `cd /LEVEL-1/LEVEL-2/LEVEL-3`